# Apple App Transport Security (ATS) for Enterprise Application

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-transport-security

I am developing an enterprise application. So far every thing was working fine in simulator but when i deploy it on physical devices it crashes. Crash is happening because app is connecting to web services via "HTTP" instead of "HTTPS".

I have added the ATS exceptions in `info.plist` file. I need to know that enterprise application will continue to work after 2016 (Apple's Deadline) with `HTTP`?

Application will be hosted in our own servers, and apple doesn't review the enterprise applications.

**Update 1**
I just need to know enterprise application will continue to work after 2016 with this ATS exceptions or not ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.xxxxxxx.xxx</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.009</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.0</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Fonts/Montserrat-Black.otf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Montserrat-Bold.otf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Montserrat-ExtraBold.otf</string>
        <string>Fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf</string>
    </array>

  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
      <key>http://xxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxx</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.0</string>
        <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>

</dict>
```

Comment: Can you share contents of plist?...

Comment: @sanman done, i have added the ATS related attributes. i only need to know that this ATS attribute will continue to work after 2016 for ENTERPRISE application available to specific customers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any Apple App Store Submissions starting 2017, still can request a App Transport Security (ATS) exception that will be reviewed by Apple. You will need to highly restrict your exception list and not allowed blanket arbitrary http loads. The reviewers can still reject your submission and request additional information.

i.e. Apps requesting US Government NOAA Images over a non-secure channel ***might*** to allowed since NOAA currently does not support HTTPS/SSL for those weather radar images.... Again, up to the Apple reviewers...

#### WKWebView, UIWebView, WebView:

> `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` lets you have a strict ATS dictionary but still load arbitrary content in a web view (WKWebView, UIWebView, WebView)

#### Non-secure local networking:

> `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` allows loading of local resources without disabling ATS for the rest of your app

#### Media content that is already encrypted:

> `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia` disables all ATS restrictions for media that your app loads using the AV Foundation framework. Employ this key only for loading media that are already encrypted, such as files protected by FairPlay or by secure HLS, and that do not contain personalized information.

#### Enterprise Applications:

These do not get Apple reviewed, thus disabling ATS is allowed until a possible future version of iOS that would disallow non-secure traffic, *but that is far from a best practice*

- Enterprise data accessed non-securely?

If your Enterprise app requires non-secure local network-based resources, use the new `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` exception instead.

If your Enterprise app requires non-secure Enterprise resources obtained over the public internet, you might have security issues that are beyond the scope of just iOS App Transport Security issues.

Comment: @SushilHangover Thank you for such a good explanation. Application is only accessing data by REST APIs. Not any private/personal info of end users is included in it. I know HTTP is not a good practice but for now i can't use HTTPs.?
So i can use HTTP until future version of iOS where the will not allow disabling ATS.

Comment: @BasitZIa **Yes**.... as long as it is not a Store based app and until some possible future version of iOS at disables arbitrary non-secure loads...

Answer (score -1):

Try allowing the Arbitrary Loads under ATS.

Comment: this should be comment!!

Comment: @Lion he does not have enough reputation so I think its fine.

Comment: Sorry Sir Lion for the comment. Actually i m beginner in IOS Development. and when my practice app was crashed due to sending request i came to know that APPLE don't allow to send request to known servers thats y i commented that because in query 1 of the sentence was that the app get crashed.

Answer (score -1):

There are many applications working with `HTTP`, I mean without `ssl` right now, so it is not issue of worry except security which `ssl` can add. But in future if apple totally restricted web service without `ssl` or `https` then you and everyone have to configure `ssl` in server, and no one can say surely right now that it will work after 2016 or not! Right now you can use `hhtp`!

Comment: after 2016 it will not work i know that. apple wouldn't approve applications which will be using HTTP. But i am asking about Enterprise applications. Which will not be hosted on iTunes store. only distributed to specific customers via our own servers.

Comment: if `http` will be restricted then i think you will not able to use whether it is distributed to specific customers or via appstore!!

Comment: @BasitZIa As SushiHangover explained you will still be able to disable ATS where required, but you will need to provide justification as part of your review notes